# Cypress mock geolocation

Tags: cypress

I'm developing a website using current user geolocation (throught [geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API))

Is there a way to mock **user geolocation** (gps position) on cypress (chrome) ? I didn't found anything on that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes.**

You can stub the `geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` function from the window object.

```
cy.visit('/test', {
  onBeforeLoad (win) {
    // e.g., force Barcelona geolocation
    const latitude = 41.38879;
    const longitude = 2.15899;
    cy.stub(win.navigator.geolocation, 'getCurrentPosition').callsFake((cb) => {
      return cb({ coords: { latitude, longitude } });
    });
  },
});
```

In fact, there is a [thread in GitHub](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2671) talking about this Cypress (desired) feature.

I've posted the solution that works for me using Cypress v4.10.0, feel free to improve the code.